# Comment trouver la signification d'un mot que j'ai entendu ?

Tags: prononciation, ressources

Parfois, il m'arrive d'entendre un mot que je ne connais pas. Naturellement je ne sais pas comment il est écrit. Comment je peux faire pour trouver ce mot, juste en connaissant à peu près sa sonorité ?

Comment: En fait, tu cherches un système de reconnaissance de la parole.

Answer (score 4):

Le [Trésor de la Fangue Française informatisé](http://atilf.atilf.fr/) a une interface qui permet une saisie phonétique.

Comment: C'est mieux que rien, mais je ne pense pas que ce soit très pratique. Visiblement ce n'est pas possible d'afficher les mots qui ont une phonétique proche de celle qu'on a entrée, et ça ne marche que si on connait la phonétique (simplifiée) exacte. Par ailleurs, je suis incapable de trouver *œuvre* avec ce système (pas de `/œ/` ?), il n'y a aussi aucune distinction entre `/ø/` et `/ɛ/`. Pour finir, les résultats ne donnent même pas la prononciation précise, il faut avoir un deuxième support sous la main pour affiner la recherche… Bref, j'ai comme un doute que ce soit utilisable…

Answer (score 3):

Rester à l'oral.

Si c'est avec un interlocuteur joignable, lui demander la signification de ce mot.

S'il n'est pas joignable (une personne entendue à la radio), demander à une personne vivante joignable. Une langue vit et se comprend avec les vivants, pas avec les dictionnaires ; les dictionnaires, c'est uniquement pour approfondir, pour la culture.

La technique de compréhension de l'oral est différente de la compréhension de l'écrit : à l'oral on traite un ensemble, un flux, au mieux une phrase, que l'on découpe ensuite en mots (qui permettent de faire le lien avec l'écrit). Pour comprendre l'oral il faut rester à cet ensemble, au flux, et demander l'explication de cet ensemble.

C'est de cette explication orale de l'oral que te viendra le mot écrit.

(on reprend le débat *méthode globale / méthode classique* ? )

Answer (score 2):

Une méthode serait d'écrire le mot comme il se prononce puis de rechercher une meilleure orthographe à partir de celui-ci. Pour cela, deux moyens me viennent à l'esprit :

- Tu peux d'abord essayer de l'écrire « comme il se prononce » puis faire une recherche sur Google à partir de ce mot mal orthographié. Tu devrais alors trouver des réponses. Si j'ai cité Google c'est parce qu'il a tendance à corriger de lui-même les recherches et qu'il pourrait de ce fait orthographier correctement le mot.
- Écrire le mot comme il se prononce dans un logiciel de traitement de texte (Word, Libre Office, Apache Open Office… ce ne sont pas les logiciels qui manquent) puis le passer au correcteur orthographique qui proposera alors de bonnes orthographes.